# how to force cell editor in jtable to accept edits

Tags: java, jtable

i have a jtable with multiple editable cells

when someone presses the "save button" on the menu, it doesn't save the last value that is still currently being edited. (unless they tab out of the cell first)

i can check it is being edited by calling .isEditing() which returns true.

What i would prefer to do is trigger that the cell editing is complete, and it can show any validation errors, and if none, then save. (without the user having to tab out first)

can someone please point me in the right direction

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can manually call:

```
JTable table;
table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
```

This should cause the table to stop editing at that cell.  By overriding the `stopCellEditing()` method of your `TableCellEditor` and returning false under certain circumstances, you can indicate that the cell's value is currently invalid and thus editing cannot be stopped at that time.

Comment: Exactly +1, I have written this way but did not remember API method to call :)

Comment: If you override your `DefaultTableModel`'s `getColumnClass` to return a value other than `String.class`, then it will return false if it is invalid input. For example, if you make a column `Float.class`, it will return false if it couldn't exit the cell because the entered text wasn't a valid `float`.

Answer (score 6):

when you have a jtable with multiple editable cells

when someone presses the "save button" on the menu, it doesn't save the last value then please add the below peace of code

The first is to have the table automatically stop editing and save the data. This can be done by setting a property on the table:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...);
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

It will make sure that when someone presses the any button on the menu, it saves the last edited value also.

Comment: This is a simpler solution than Mark Peter's answer, taking advantage of Swing's built-in validation. However, it doesn't allow you to stop the process if the input is invalid. Instead, it reverts to the previous value if it was invalid.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, edited/added value is present in cell editor component by default it is EditBox, BUT do not present in table model. If it is possible try to check cell editor component it should help you.